# Nativescript-Vue Javascript import custom elements like Button, FieldView, Label ecc

Tags: android, ios, nativescript-vue

Is this possibile to create a `component_1.vue` with a single element like a `Textfield` and export it like this:

```
<template>
  <TextField
    :text="textFieldValue"
    hint="Hint here.."
    class="textfield"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Custom_TextField',
    data: function () {
        return {
            class: class,
            text: text 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And the use it in another `component_2.vue` ?

```
<template>
  <Label text="Component_1 below" />
  <Custom_TextField />
</template>

<script>
import component_1.vue from "@/components/component_1.vue"

export default {
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible.

A good example can be found in the Nativescript samples page (Restaurant Menu App - [market.nativescript.org](https://market.nativescript.org/?tab=samples&framework=vue&category=all_samples))

And here its playground code: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=sPOHNo&v=278

If you open the Home.vue component you can see 3 custom components being imported and then used in the Nativescript layout on the top.

Custom components in Home.vue:

```
import navBottom from "./custom/navBottom";
import Item from "./custom/item";
import Category from "./custom/category";
```

Custom components used in the Home.vue layout:

```
<item :item="item" @clicked="showItem(item)" />
<Category :item="item"> </Category>
<navBottom row="3" />
```

You can see the custom components under the custom folder of the app

Hope that helps.